# Using pkgbuild to install multiple files at different locations

Tags: macos, packaging, software-distribution, pkg-config

Say I have a .app and a .dylib file that I need to install in different locations, one in /Applications and another one in /usr/local/lib. Is it possible to do this through the command line with pkgbuild? I was able to build a .pkg with this same behavior but only with the GUI application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative, while not the most ideal, it does the job for me. It's using packagesbuild commandline that comes with Packages (http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/Packages/about.html). It lets you create a .pkg file through the command line, but you need to create a .pkgproj file, which you create with the Packages application. You can install various files in different locations this way.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to do all the file-shuffling during a postinstall script.  I'm new to pkgbuild in the last week or so, but I'm using a postinstall script successfully to move files around.  The --install-location in the generated pkg is actually a temporary holding area.  The script creates the final target directory, and copies files into it from the temporary holding area.  I'm only copying to one target directory, but multiple dirs shouldn't be an issue.  The last lines of the postinstall script (just before the obligatory exit(0)) remove that temporary holding area and everything in it.

I didn't find much documentation on pkgbuild scripting.  [Here's a good one.](https://macadmins.psu.edu/files/2019/07/psumac2019-345-Installer-Package-Scripting-Making-your-deployments-easier-one-at-a-time.pdf)  It uses bash, I'm using python, but the same concepts hold true: the arguments are as described, and it must return 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can make same directory structure in root path

In your case you can make a directory RootDir first.

`cd RootDir` and make a directory called Applications,and move your .app to this directory.
then make `usr/local/lib` directorys in `RootDir` and move .dylib file to `RootDir/usr/local/lib`

last use `pkgbuild --root RootDir --install-location /`